# Calling aspnet Membership ResetPassword stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I would like to call the aspnet Membership ResetPassword stored procedure called: `aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword` within the `aspnetdb` database.

When I look at the `SqlMembershipProvider` class there is a ResetPassword method but this is not useful as I cannot pass the parameter PasswordFormat as I can with the stored procedure.

Can anyone advise how I can call this stored procedure explictly from the codebehind of an aspx page in c#?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Encryption mode to store the password it will be better to use ChangePassword Method like the following:

```
_MembershipUser.ChangePassword(_MembershipUser.GetPassword(),"NewP@ssw0rd");
```

Answer (score 0):

The PasswordFormat is a flag that represents whether the ASP is storing the password in the database as either hashed, encrypted, or plain text.  This is typically specified only once (in the web.config).

```
passwordFormat="Hashed"
```

It can be found in the Membership sub-section of the Configuration section of the web.config as seen below...

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         applicationName="/"
            />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

As stated earlier, just use the ChangePassword method, and the PasswordFormat setting will be pulled from the web.config automatically.